# How do I kill a task / coroutine in Julia?

Tags: task, julia, coroutine

```
using HttpServer

http = HttpHandler() do request::Request, response::Response
    show(request)
    Response("Hello there")
end

http.events["error"] = (client, error) -> println(error)
http.events["listen"] = (port) -> println("Listening on $port")
server = Server(http)

t = @async run(server, 3000)
```

This starts a simple little web server asynchronously.  The problem is I have no idea how to stop it.  I've been going through the Julia documentation and trying to find some function that will remove this task from the queue (`kill`, `interrupt`, etc.) but nothing seems to work.

How can I kill this task?

Comment: A simple solution to your problem would be to reimplement [run](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HttpServer.jl/blob/master/src/HttpServer.jl#L204) with a cancelable loop. Julia uses libuv, so `accept` really is [uv_accept](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/stream.html#c.uv_accept). See esp. [uv_connection_cb](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/stream.html#c.uv_connection_cb).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually looking for a little more general than that.  The HTTP server is just an example of an asynchronously running task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see an official way to end a task specifically, but I think the general solution was [the addition of throwto,](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/5a0b65ba2425b83ebd650e83c44b774e1448bdd0) which allows you to immediately schedule a task with a pending exception.

```
...
t = @async run(server, 3000)
...
ex = InterruptException()
Base.throwto(t, ex)
close(http.sock) # ideally HttpServer would catch exception to cleanup
```