# how to kill a task in Julia?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, julia

I have a Julia code where I need to execute two operation in a parallel way.
My problem is that I need to stop and kill one operation if it take too much time.

I tried with the `Task` but now I can't find how to kill a task. My code is:

```
function mytask(myargs, ch)
    # do some work (optimize a problem with Gurobi)
    # that can go on for a very long time
    put!(ch, computationResult)
end

ch = Channel(1)
task = @async mytask(args, ch)

# now the main task does some other work
# and at the end

if isready(ch)
    taskResult = take!(ch)
else
    # the result of th async task became useless
    # so here I need to kill the async task
end

# continue the execution
```

I found this [similar old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209663/how-do-i-kill-a-task-coroutine-in-julia) but I think the solution is no longer supported because I can't find the `throwto` method in the documentation and I also tried it but I get this error message

```
WARNING: Workqueue inconsistency detected: shift!(Workqueue).state != :queued
ERROR (unhandled task failure): InterruptException:
```

I'm not forced to use tasks, I can use thread processes or any other solution as long as it works

Comment: `throwto` is not documented, but it is defined here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/a882d9bf183fc93319002c9158f406f0755c202e/base/event.jl#L204. It is a small wrapper around `yieldto`, which is defined a few lines above (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/a882d9bf183fc93319002c9158f406f0755c202e/base/event.jl#L180). In the doc string of that function, it says that it's use is discouraged. Maybe `yield` works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote that while waiting for long computation to finish you need to do some other processing in the foreground. `@async` provides green-threading mechanism only and hence is inappropriate for your problem - your program would be still able to use only one `Thread` at a time. Additionally, currently in Julia tasks do not support killing mechanism (unless you do it in some way programmatically yourself).

The clean solution is to use the Julia `Distributed` mechanism. Below is a sample code snippet.

The code starts long-running computations - depending on whether the computation finishes within the declared time the results or collected or the process is killed.

Enjoy!

```
using Distributed

Distributed.addprocs(1)  #we add one worker process that will be the 
                         #long-running background computation
wid = workers()[end]     #take last worker (there is just one anyway)
const result = RemoteChannel(()->Channel{Tuple}(1));
@everywhere function longrun(result,c=3,time=0)
    #write whatever code you need here
    for i in 1:c
        sleep(time)
        println("Working $i at $(myid())")
    end
    #we use the RemoteChannel to collect the result
    put!(result, (c,time,999999, myid()))
end

function ready_or_not(result,wid)
    if !isready(result)
        println("Computation at $wid will be terminated")
        rmprocs(wid)
        return nothing
    else
        return take!(result)
    end
end


remote_do(longrun,wid,result) #this takes far less than a second...
sleep(1)
show(ready_or_not(result,wid)) # .. and you should see the result

remote_do(longrun,wid,result,10,3) #this takes 30s
sleep(7)
show(ready_or_not(result,wid)) #ready_or_not() terminates the worker process
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
I think this solved my problem, but I can't call other functions inside the longrun function. 
In particular I have a module defined by myself and I would like to call a function inside the longrun function.
Should I put @everywhere on every function of the module to make its functions on callable?

Comment: I don't know if it's a clean solution but I with `@everywhere include(ModuleFilePath)` and then `@everywhere import ModuleName: functionName`.
Please notify me if something is wrong or dirty.

Comment: Using `@everywhere` is absolutely fine. However, note that it will cause to execute the command (e.g. load your module) on all processes including the master process. Sometimes this is what you want, sometimes you do not care, and sometimes you wish to do that only on slave processes. For the latter scenario I put the slave code into a separate file (.e.g. `slave_code.jl`) and use `fetch(@spawnat slave_worker_id include("slave_code.jl"))`